# R console debugger: how can I time each step?

Tags: r

While debugging an R function in the interactive shell I would like to be able to time each step, like, for example, with `\timing on` in `psql`. Does R debugger support anything similar? I know about profiler packages or ability to track time manually, but I am interested in a simple solution that I could use interactively whenever I `debug()` a function or call `browser()`.

Comment: No, there's no way to link profiling to the debugger.  You can turn profiling on and off, but that's probably not sufficient for your needs.